# Setting multiple user/password for Connection Class

Tags: java, sql, swing, connection

Hi guys I have an app with multiple profiles ("Admin" , "Delegate") , and in my database I have the same Users to make operations. I wanna set the database user with a ComboBox Where users Log-in and use that data through all my Database calls according to the user profile.

My connection data is Hardcoded in a Connection class SQL like:

```
public class SQL {

private PreparedStatement PStatement;
private Connection connection;
private String user;
private String pass;


public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getPass() {
    return pass;
}

public void setPass(String pass) {
    this.pass = pass;
}

public Connection dbConection() {

    String loggedUser = "root" ;
    String loggedUserPass = "";

    try {
        Class.forName(cf.DB_DRIVER);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(cf.SERVER_URL + cf.SERVER_DB, loggedUser, loggedUserPass);

        if (connection == null) {
            throw new SQLException("Connection no established");
        }            
        return connection;

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), cf.WINDOW_TITLE, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);            
    } 
    return connection;
}
```

Every time I used my DAOs I have to Call the SQL Class:

```
public int insert(Users user) throws SQLException {
    SQL sql = new SQL();
    query = sql.createPStatement(cf.INSERT_USER_DATA);
    query.setInt(1, user.getUserId());
    query.setInt(2, user.getUserCencos());
    query.setInt(3, user.getUserProfile());
    query.setString(4, user.getUserPassword());
    query.setString(5, user.getUserName());
    query.setString(6, user.getUserPosition());
    query.setString(7, user.getUserOffice());
    try {
        result = query.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException | NumberFormatException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        SQLUtils.closeQuietly(sql.dbConection());
        SQLUtils.closeQuietly(query);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But everytime I instantiate , it takes the Hardcoded values.

How I can set the Connect Data `user` and `password` overriding the "Burned" connection Strings in the SQL Class?.

Thanks for your help to this newbie fellow programmer.

Comment: Remove `String loggedUser = "root" ;` and `String loggedUserPass = "";`, replace them with `user` and `pass` instead

Answer (score 0):

I have a class `cf` with public static variables.

```
public class cf {    

public static String DB_USER;
public static String DB_PASSWORD;  
public static String INV_DEL="delegado";
public static String INV_DELXXX="123";
public static String A_="root";
public static String A_XXX="";
getter and setter...

public static void setLogin(String profile){

    switch(profile){            
        case "Admin":
            cf.setDB_USER(cf.A_);  
            cf.setDB_PASSWORD(cf.A_XXX);  
        break;    

        case "Delegado":
            cf.setDB_USER(cf.INV_DEL);  
            cf.setDB_PASSWORD(cf.INV_DELXXX);  
        break;         
    }

}
```

So in my SQL Class I use the static variables instead of the instance variables.

```
public Connection dbConection() {

try {
        Class.forName(cf.DB_DRIVER);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(cf.SERVER_URL +    cf.SERVER_DB, cf.getDB_USER(), cf.getDB_PASSWORD());
  more SQL stuff...
}
```

So when the user Log-in with the button, in the comboBox , so I set the static variables ,

```
private void loginButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {        

profile = profileComBoBox.getSelectedItem().toString();        
    setLogin(profile);
do login stuff...       
}
```

Is not that elegant but is sometime to start.